# To compare the dates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing my first application ever. I'm using Swift. A user allowed to take certain action only once a day. I need to write proper code to check if a user already has taken the action today. Unfortunately I barely have an idea how to build the code. Especially I'm not aware how to declare variable with nil for those users who start use the app for the first time.

```
@IBAction func yesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

// check if the user have already clicked 'yes' button today
// if true then do some something
// else show the alert

}
```

Thank you so much for your answers!

Comment: You need to try to write the code and then if there are problems post the code and ask for help. Hint: `NSDate`.

Comment: that makes sense. Wait a minute please. I'll do my suggestion right now.

Comment: I suggest you to learn the language first (the [official reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496) is a good starting point) and at the same time read some tutorials (appcoda and raywenderlich have  good ones) or books. If this is your 1st experience, tutorials can really help you a lot.

Comment: @Zaph I has idea how to save the date with NSDate and Persistent Storage, but the plow is not obvious for me for those users who are just have started to use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not terribly complicated, but you will need to learn several tricks, if you haven't already. I'll try to explain in a code.

You can use standard user defaults to save some value, so that it is persisted even if the user closes the app.

```
// To get current date and time
let currentDate = NSDate()

// To save it to user defaults - do this when the user presses the button
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentDate, forKey: "myDate")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

// To retrieve the date from user defaults - and to check if the button was pressed
let myDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myDate") as? NSDate

// myDate will be nil if it was not set yet (first use). Let's check it for nil
if let lastPushedDate = myDate {

    // get current date a time to compare with the saved value
    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let secondsInADay: NSTimeInterval = 3600 * 25

    // check how many seconds elapsed since last date and do something if the interval is long enough
    if dateNow.timeIntervalSinceDate(lastPushedDate) >= secondsInADay {
        println("We are fine, button can be pushed")
    }
}
```

So in your function yesButtonPressed you will want to do the following:

- Retrieve the date from user defaults.
- If it was never used, it will be nil.
- If it was used, compare it with current time and decide if the elapsed time interval was long enough.
- After the button has been pushed, save the current date to the user defaults
- As a next step, for better user experience, you would probably want to have the button disabled if the time did not elapse yet and only enable it if the button can be pushed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! But could you tell me how myDate variable can be nil if you have already assigned currentDate value to it?

Comment: It should not be in the example above, but will be in real world code before the user pushes the button for the first time and you specifically asked about it.

Comment: I see. Could you please tell me how to create NSDate object with no value? And how to assign nil value to proper variable?

Comment: If you did not use the NSUserDefaults, you would create NSDate with

Comment: You don't need that for the scenario above. NSUserDefaults will return nil if no value was previously set. For then nil handling take a look at optional variables (here NSDate?) and "if let" functionality.

Comment: I guess in the scenario you had suggested above myDate was never be nil because currentDate was not nil. Most likely that is the reason why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Look your myDate var has always the actual date when the action made. There are no case for it to has nil value. Because "let currentDate = NSDate()". Right?

Comment: Yes. The code was intended to show the individual actions you will need to take, but for your yesButtonPressed function you will want to use them in different order (see the bullet points below the code). So in your code you will start with retrieving the value from user defaults, where it can be nil. You will do the let currentDate = ... only if the user is allowed to press the button so that you ca save the new date back to user defaults.